# Matlab - set like datatype?

Tags: matlab, math-software

I need to work with Matlab again but it's long ago that I did so the last time. So I need your help (searching for "set" leads only to how to set colors of axis and so...). How can I achieve a set like behavior of an array (or any other similar datatype).

The thing is I have a initial set of vectors and want to add some new vectors to it but I don't want doubles.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is about the *Matlab* computer programming language, not mathematics, and hence should be migrated.

Comment: Agree about the migration.  Meanwhile, you may want to look at the [Java collections](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html), which are available from within MATLAB.

Comment: sure let's migrate that (and my other matlab topics too). how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `A`be the $k\times n$ matrix containing your first vectors and `v` be the $1\times n$ vector you want to add in your "set" `A`. Then 
`B = unique([A;v],'rows')` will either output you `B = A` if `v` already belongs to `A` or `B = [A;v]` if `v` is a new vector of the set of vectors `A`.